# Angular common not contain ControlGroup

Tags: c#, angular

Im new to TypeScript and trying to accomplish simple things through tutorials, but without success yet (too many tutorials and things just vanished from Angular or not working at all, or working tutorials covers just changes in std files).

Im trying to use `<form>` tag to input some data and then process it in MainPageComponent, the problem is in this line:

```
import { FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from "@angular/common";
```

IntelliSence tells me there is no such modules in angular. Where I can find them? What command beside I should run for it to actually compile?

Answer (score 1):

They are in the forms module

```
import { FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
```

Comment: You are a hero, sir. Very hard to understand why youtube tutorial not working! But it still says there is no ControlGroup in this module....

Comment: Perhaps outdated. In older versions forms stuff was exported by `common`

Comment: Sorry, don't know about that. I'm not using TS locally (only for SO Plunker), but there should be questions with answers that explain that.